# Class decorator to add the “identify“ class method which returns a class name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a task to Implement the class decorator to add the “identify“ class method which returns a class name with the information passed in the decorator.
For example:

```
typescript
    @identifier('example')
    class Test {}

const test = new Test();
console.log(test['identify']()); // Test-example
```

The problem is that I found out documentation where is written that I can get class name only doing const x = new Class Y and use .name function, but in my case, I don't know how the class or variable where the instance will be stored. Maybe getting this information from test units could get this done but I don't know the perfect approach cuz I'm new in typescript.
This is my try of doing the function :

```
const identifier = (text : string) => {
 console.log(test.constructor.name)
return test.constructor.name
}
```

Yes, it's barely anything, but I don't know from where to start.
Unit tests :

```
describe('identifier', () => {
    it('should return Test-example from identify', () => {
        @identifier('example')
        class Test {}
        const test = new Test();
        assert.strictEqual(test['identify'](), 'Test-example');
    });

    it('should return ClassA-prototype from identify', () => {
        @identifier('prototype')
        class ClassA {}
        const test = new ClassA();
        assert.strictEqual(test['identify'](), 'ClassA-prototype');
    })
});
```

Could you guys please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Which iterator proposal version are you using? Please also add the code of your `identifier` function, even if it's currently not working.

Comment: Uhm,its not being i think

Comment: "*I found out documentation where is written that I can get class name only doing const x = new Class Y and use .name function*" - no idea what you're talking about. What documentation did you find, can you link that please? You can access the name directly on `Y.name`, you don't need an instance `x` for that. And `.name` is no a function.

Comment: Yes,i do have problems with spelling therminology because i am a new starter in this direction,i found that info on some posts on stackoverflow and other websites,i closed that tabs already,but again,if i use Y.name,i dont know y..

Comment: "*if i use Y.name,i dont know y*" - uh, it works for `anyClass.name`, you just need to use the reference to the class that you have in your decorator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this function that solves my issue :

```
function identifier(...args: any): ClassDecorator {
    return function <TFunction extends Function>(
        target: TFunction
    ): TFunction | any {
        var identify = target.prototype.identify;
        Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, 'identify', {
            value: function() {
                return target.name + "-" + args;
            }
        });
        return identify;
    };
}
```

It creates the identify method for the class,pass to the method the class name and the string from parantheses and then return it.